# Team Foundation Server 2015 compatible with Microsoft Test Manager 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-2015

I am using Microsoft Test Manager 2010, and we are upgrading to TFS 2015.
Question: is it full compatible because we have project, tc, and other items already working.

I see that only need to install GDR : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2736182 for VS 2010.

But is this only thing what we need to do ? There is no actualy answer on :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements#ClientcompatibilityVisualStudio

Will I have the supported platforms and configurations from Microsoft Test Manager 2010 for connecting, making builds for automated tests etc...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes MTM 2010 will work with TFS 2015.  Obviously you won't be able to use the new testing features though, such as exploratory tests in the 2010 client.

Comment: Thanks, I was worry about my own test created in mtm2010 and builds, conected agents controllers for shure.